# What are the steps to create an explicit function from an implicit instruction?

Tags: functions

I want to develop a method to compute the seed value after `n` steps.
I first wanted to use a loop, but I thought maybe someone comes up with a nice single expression and could also say something about the process.

I guess you have to use mathematical induction to solve that...

$x_0 = \mathtt{seed}$

$ x_1 = (x_0 \cdot \mathtt{0x5DEECE66D} + \mathtt{0xB})~\mathtt{AND}~((1~ \mathtt{SHIFTL}~48) - 1) $

$x_n = \dots$

All the values are **64-bit java long** numbers. More information can be found here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#next%28int%29. What I basically want to do is to copy an instance of Random object, so that copy behaves same.

Comment: I managed to create a copy of a random object http://stackoverflow.com/a/18531276/1809463. But I'm still interested in the solution, though.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using [this service](http://www.random.org/).

Or, if you want to write the code yourself, I suggest starting [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generation#Computational_methods).